# Printing list of trainstations going through

Tags: python

So I got a list of trainstations for example

stations = ['Amsterdam', 'Rotterdam', 'Eindhoven', 'Utrecht', 'Zwolle', 'Groningen']

I got the following def function:

```
def test():
    beginstation = input('Enter beginstation: ')
    laststation = input('Enter laststation: ')
    print('You\'re traveling from {} to {}'.format(beginstation, laststation))
    print('You are going through the following stations: {}'.format(???))
```

If I take the train from Amsterdam to Zwolle, how do i print out the stations i go through? (Rotterdam, Eindhoven and Utrecht).

I'm a beginner at programming and looking for some help :) Its not homework! I'm just trying to get better and better.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want the user to input the stations they are going through, or you just want them to be listed? Are the train stations you are going through going to depend on where you start and where you end, and you want the program to already know that information?

Comment: I want that the user enters his deparature and arrival station. For example: Departure: Amsterdam, Arrival: Zwolle. He will go through Rotterdam, Eindhoven and Utrecht. I want to print those.  btw i forgot to mention is that its only a one way. So you can go from left to right only  and not the opposite.

Comment: The `list.index` method can help with this task. And once you have the indices of the first & last stations you can use slicing, eg `stations[2:4]`. And you an do reverse journeys with  `stations[3:1:-1]`

Comment: Thanks guys i got it =D I forgot about slicing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing, look at this code and then replace the Rotterdam and Zwolle for your inputs.

```
if stations.index('Rotterdam') < stations.index('Zwolle'):
    visited = stations[stations.index('Rotterdam'):stations.index('Zwolle')+1]
else:
    visited = stations[stations.index('Zwolle'):stations.index('Rotterdam')-1:-1]

print('You are going through the following stations: {}'.format(', '.join(visited)))
```

Comment: Ouch, this is exactly what @PM 2Ring was talking about in his comment.